# Finding Convergence of a Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

According to WolframAlpha this series converges, but I can't find out how to properly use the limit comparison test with it. Can anyone at least tell me what my $b_n$ might be?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{n}\cdot\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}n\right)$$

Comment: I edited your post as I understood it. If there are any mistakes - feel free to edit it. Please use $\LaTeX$ to typeset math. You can find a nice guide here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully someone will follow up with an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$, hence when you see $\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}n\right)$,
you should immediately think of $\left(\frac{\pi}n\right)^2$. So try $b_n=\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}n\right)^2=\frac1{n\sqrt n}$.
(and use the limit comparison test)

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

For all $x$, we have
$$
\sin^2(x)\le x^2
$$
Thus,
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{n}\cdot\sin^2(\pi/n)\right|\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi^2}{n^{3/2}}
$$
which converges by the [$p$-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test#Usage) ( $\frac32\gt1$ ).